# Will "in-block" directives overwrite "inblock" task directives?

Tags: syntax, ansible, yaml

I have a block specified in a ansible playbook like this:

```
- block:
  - name: DO SOMETHING
    shell: whatevercommand -flag test
    **become: true
    become_user: root**
  - name: DO SOMETHING ELSE
    shell: whateversecondcommand -secondflag testsecond
  when: do_status | success
  become: true
  become_user: root
```

Will the inline "become/become_user" be kept for that task, or will the block take precedence over the inline directive?

Comment: Why not spend 30 seconds to test it yourself?

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov Because if this question is answered here, other people will not need to invest those 30 seconds. It is a good question since this is not explicitly defined in the Ansible documentation (at least I could not find it).

Comment: You can post answer to your own question to help others.

Comment: Yes, but an answer derived from testing is not as valuable as one from someone knowing the code.

Comment: Konstantin, you're right. at the time of posting, I had not a test suite up, only access to a suite that targeted "not-for-test" stuff. Lazy on my part, and a good reminder to have a test suite available :)

Flyx, one of the reason I asked was exactly that. But, I'll try my self and post here :)

Comment: For the record:
The inline directive takes precidence over the block level directives.
So, a task within a block, that has directives defined, will get those directives, not the blocks directives.

Answer (score 0):

Tested it myself now so, for the record: The inline directive takes precidence over the block level directives. So, a task within a block, that has directives defined, will get those directives, not the blocks directives.